# Camel routes added from my custom component do not start

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel 2.19.1.

I am writing a custom Camel component. It only does producer. The component interacts with another system by using an async processor that invokes another set of routes. I add the other set of routes from my component's onCamelContextStarted():

```
@Override
public void onCamelContextStarted(CamelContext context, boolean alreadyStarted) throws Exception {
    if (!alreadyStarted) {
        context.setUseMDCLogging(true);
  context.addRoutes(context.getInjector().newInstance(OtherRoutes.class));
    }
}
```

When I run a test on this, I can see that OtherRoutes is getting created and it's `configure()` is called. But apparently the routes are not started. An exchange sent to one of them just hangs.

How do I start OtherRoutes's routes?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use

Comment: Camel version 2.19.1

Answer (score 1):

Ah okay but you cannot add and have new routes started from this callback. This callback is triggered while Camel is starting up its existing routes, and has a "failsafe" kinda mode that new routes are not started.

So you need to use another way of adding and starting your routes.

Comment: Any suggestions? These routes are added by a custom component. Maybe have the custom component create and start its own camel context?

Comment: You can use EventNotifier and react on the CamelContextStartedEvent where you can add the routes.

Comment: I logged a ticket to add an extension to this StartupListener in next big release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11985

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by creating a separate CamelContext from my component (in doStart() ) and starting that. Happy to hear suggestions, but at this point it's more or less working.